# Is this a pun or a metaphor 'I had and wasn't a perambulator'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is excerpted from the author Max Beerbohm's essay *Going Out for a Walk*:

> *It is a fact that not once in all my life have I gone out for a walk. I have been taken out for walks; but that is another matter. Even while I trotted prattling by my nurse’s side I regretted the good old days **when I had, and wasn’t, a perambulator**.*

I looked up the word *perambulator* in the dictionary(American Heritage and Oxford), and found it means *a pram*, a baby carriage. And I also looked up *perambulate*, and it means *walk* or *travel around*. So I wonder if the last sentence *I had, and wasn't, a perambulator* is a pun: the author had a pram but he wasn't a great walker when he was a baby. Otherwise it would be weird to me that the author said he *wasn't* a baby carriage. Am I right about this?

---

Edit:

I find [this review](https://www.iluenglish.com/going-out-for-a-walk-by-max-beerbohm-summary-and-analysis/)(please click if you are interested) of 'Going Out for a Walk' on the internet.

And it says:

> *Beerbohm begins by stating that he is an inveterate opponent of the
>   habit of walking. Even when he was a toddler, he used to regret the
>   good old days when he was an infant. He didn’t have to walk then,
>   since he had a perambulator. **He wasn’t a pram and so nobody would ever
>   forcefully take him out for a walk.***

The reviewer thinks Beerbohm compared himself to a pram(*perambulator*), i.e. Beerbohm didn't have to be pushed around like a pram. So *pram* is understood as a metaphor.

Then I am confused. What does the author really mean by saying 'I wasn't a perambulator?

Does he mean:

1) when he was a baby, he was not someone who perambulates?

or

2) when he was a baby, he didn't have to be forcefully taken out for a walk like people did with a pram?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis): "I had" refers to the meaning of "perambulator" as a baby carriage (from which te word "pram" is derived"). "I was" refers to its meaning of "someone who walks".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's technically a pun or just some wordplay, but you are definitely interpreting it correctly, yes.